# Where is Java 6u65-apple installed?

Tags: sdkman

I see that Java 6u65-apple is one of the available Java versions. Where does this JDK get installed on macOS? Will this JDK coexist with the newer (newest) Oracle Java JRE and JDK?

Comment: Well past the end of its support life.  Why would you want a JVM older than JDK 8?

Comment: Yes, you and I know that, but my customer is stuck using Java 6 for the foreseeable future. Therefore, I'm stuck developing for it. And no, Java 8 in v6 compliance mode won't work, either.

Comment: You have an obligation to tell your customer that they are at risk until they upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I know. They are well aware of the problem, but are under legal, contractual, and budgetary constraints that can't be solved at my level. But, this conversation doesn't get me any closer to an answer to my question.

Comment: It goes in /opt folder in Ubuntu.  Since Mac is also Unix, perhaps that will be a clue. Why not just sudo install and see?

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you intend using sdkman on macOS High Sierra. It should install it below ~/.sdkman but it seems not to work. This is what I and some others get, see for example https://gitter.im/sdkman/user-issues?at=5a1db5de71ad3f87363f4754

```
$ sdk install java 6u65-apple
tr: Illegal byte sequence

Apple requires that you agree with the Apple Software License Agreement
prior to installation.

The license agreement can be found in PDF format here:

  http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/JavaForOSX.pdf

Do you agree to the terms of this agreement? (Y/n): Y

Downloading: java 6u65-apple

In progress...

######################################################################## 100.0%
Binary validation passed...
We will be needing super powers...

Repackaging Java 6u65...
Attaching to the DMG...
Mounting DMG as Volume...
Volume(s) mounted successfully
Installing PKG inside DMG...
installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: Es ist bereits eine neuere Version dieses Pakets installiert.
Copy JDK Home to temp folder...
cp: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home: No such file or directory
unlink: /Users/gg/.sdkman/tmp/out/java-6u65-apple/bundle: No such file or directory
ln: /Users/gg/.sdkman/tmp/out/java-6u65-apple/bundle: No such file or directory
Preparing archive...

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr --symlinks /Users/gg/.sdkman/tmp/.zip . -i .)
Unmounting volume...
"/Volumes/Java for OS X 2015-001" unmounted successfully.
Done repackaging...
mv: rename /Users/gg/.sdkman/tmp/.zip to /Users/gg/.sdkman/archives/java-6u65-apple.zip: No such file or directory
unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/gg/.sdkman/archives/java-6u65-apple.zip, /Users/gg/.sdkman/archives/java-6u65-apple.zip.zip or /Users/gg/.sdkman/archives/java-6u65-apple.zip.ZIP.
rm: /Users/gg/.sdkman/archives/java-6u65-apple.zip: No such file or directory

Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.
```

So I found on http://osxdaily.com/2017/06/29/how-install-java-macos-high-sierra/ a link to https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US and just clicked "Download" and it does install JDK6 inside /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/ as expected. And you can switch as you like:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

And since javac 1.6 worked fine and this was the only reason for looking into sdkman I removed it entirely.

Comment: After install the jdk, `sdk install java 6u65-apple` command works again (from https://gitter.im/sdkman/user-issues?at=5a593ce0ae53c15903df5612)